# Updating hidden window using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a simple clock application. Whenever I make it disappear and restore it after a while I get an uncomfortable lag effect when my window is redrawing itself after some short period of time. I want to see changes immediately. It seems that window is not getting WM_PAINT messages while being not present on the screen (and this is actually the place I draw stuff). How to force Windows to redraw window just before showing up on the screen rather than afterwards?

Comment: Can't. But that's not your problem... Unfortunately you didn't provide any details or code to know what *is* your problem.

Comment: Of course it's not getting paint messages when it's not visible. Painting a non-visible window would be a total waste of CPU and resources, since there's nothing to be seen by an end user. It would be the equivalent of expecting the person painting your house to paint both the interior and exterior of the drywall or plaster, even though you can't see the interior of the wall. If you have a major lag, it's something you're doing (or not doing) in your own code; it's impossible to say what it might be, though, because we can't see your code from where we're sitting.

Comment: Hm maybe I used wrong words to express myself. It's not like my application is slow. Suppose I press Alt+Tab. When I do it with my application then I CAN see that there was something different drawn and the second I bring my window up it moves. But when I look at apps like Spotify then there is no such effect. Everything runs smoothly. The moment I bring up the window is has everything up and ready.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Whenever a window is uncovered (that includes minimized windows getting restored), the window is invalidated. There's nothing you have to do. Besides, `InvalidateRect` does not force a redraw. [RedrawWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911.aspx) does.

Comment: My hunch is that something is blocking the main thread of your app; which *may* be preventing your WM_PAINT code to be reached in the time you expect it to... attach a debugger or set a breakpoint and step through, or isolate until you find the issue.

Comment: InvalidateWindow==ForcesRedraw.  WM_ERASEBKGND==What is called before WM_PAINT to erase the background (and cause flicker at times).  And then to draw faster, use a MemDC.  see http://www.catch22.net/tuts/flicker-free-drawing for tips on speeding things up